What causes these streaks in my procedural hair texture?
I am trying to add a procedural cow hair texture to 4 letters out of a word, and I am noticing vertical streaks that do not seem part of the hair simulation around the edges of the mesh:

I tried changing node values and Particle settings, but nothing seems to fix this. I am happy with the way the texture looks now and I would like to keep this appearance (but minus the lighter streaks).


It's the hair direction.
When you create few hair in random positions, some faces get no hair.
Then an interpolation happens to create "children" hair, and the direction of the children varies from on hair to another.
If a hair near the edge is on the side while the top has no hair near the edge, the interpolation will create hair bending towards the side on the top face (and the other way around happens too)
If you disable the "children" hair and create more original hair with the emission, this gets solved:



You can also keep the children provided you have enough emission (I'm not sure about what the children actally do that differs them from the parents)

Thanks! I followed your advice and I am still seeing some strange artifacts around the edges (the white dots) do you also have this issue? https://imgur.com/a/jrh7Aw5

That might be too many children or too few samples in cycles. I start getting strange results if I increase the amount too much.

I am following the first part of your advice so there are no children. I will try increasing the samples - thanks

I mean, you need "more samples" or "less hair". (Not an expert advice, though)
